# How can I get the values from the main method to be accessed by the getConnection method?

Tags: java, netbeans, static-methods

I am trying to get the values that the main method would have produced and use them in the getConnection method. However when I try to access the getConnection method, null values are being returned.

I want to use the ConnectionManager class to connect to the database.

Code below.

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    public static String database;    
    public static String dbuser;
    public static String dbpassword;

    public static void main(String args[])  {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

            database = prop.getProperty("database");
            dbuser = prop.getProperty("dbuser");
            dbpassword = prop.getProperty("dbpassword");

            System.out.println(database);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + database;    
    private static String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";   
    private static String username = dbuser;   
    private static String password = dbpassword;
    private static Connection con;

    public static Connection getConnection() {

        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // log an exception. For example:
                System.out.println("Failed to create the database connection."); 
                System.out.println(url + " " + username + " " + password);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Your driver has not been found."); 
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to call the getConnection() method with parameters.

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url, String username, String password) {
    /* Your code here */
}
```

And then, call this method.

```
Connection connection = getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Comment: The values of the parameters would come from the  ...public static void main(String args[])

Answer (score 0):

Static c fields are initialized once when the class is loaded. The Connection fields are set to the ConnectionManager fields *once*, when they are still null.

To "fix" your problem, have your code in Connection use the fields in ConnectionManager:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, ConnectionManager.dbuser, ConnectionManager.dbpassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting null argument values in `DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)` calling cause you have declared them as static fields.

So you initialize them as `nulls` before you read the particular values from the `config.properties`

Let's follow the flow:

**Static initialization step:**

```
private static String username = dbuser;      //username==null; dbuser==null;
private static String password = dbpassword;  //password==null; dbpassword==null
private static Connection con;                //con==null;
```

**Method main execution:**

```
database = (prop.getProperty("database"));
dbuser = (prop.getProperty("dbuser"));          //dbuser="smth"; username==null
dbpassword = (prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));  //dbpassword ="smth"; password==null
```

**Method getConnection execution:**

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password); //username==null; //password==null;
```

P.S.: As it was previously said, it's better to use function with arguments like this:

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url, String username, String password) {
    /* Your code here */
}
```